# DOM xpath to find #text nodes and wrap in paragraph tag

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath

I would like to find all root-level #text nodes (or those with div parents) which should be wrapped inside a `<p>` tag. In the following text there should be three (or even just two) final root `<p>` tags.

```
<div>
    This text should be wrapped in a p tag.
</div>

This also should be wrapped.

<b>And</b> this.
```

The idea is to format the text nicer so that text blocks are grouped into paragraphs for HTML display. However, the following xpath I have been working out seems to fail to select the text nodes.

```
    <?php

$html = '<div>
    This text should be wrapped in a p tag.
</div>

This also should be wrapped.

<b>And</b> this.';

libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);

$dom = DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$xpath = '//text()[not(parent::p) and normalize-space()]';

foreach($xp->query($xpath) as $node) {
    $element = $dom->createElement('p');
    $node->parentNode->replaceChild($element, $node);
    $element->appendChild($node);
}

print $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Why did you put `//div` in your XPath expression if you also want to select text nodes outside of `div`s? [This fiddle](http://codepad.org/hzOefCsH) seems to do what you want.

Comment: Can you tell me what's wrong with the solution I posted above? Do you want to convert text with newlines into multiple paragraphs?

Comment: @nwellnhof, your solution is fine - but it's not an answer so I can't award you anything.

Comment: @nwellnhof, amazing! Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

OK, so let me rephrase my comment as an answer. If you want to match all text nodes, you should simply remove the `//div` part from your XPath expression. So it becomes:

```
//text()[not(parent::p) and normalize-space()]
```

Comment: How is this going to work with ``<div>this text is ok</div>But how about <b>this</b>?``?

Answer (score 2):

Your scenario has many edge-cases and the word *should* is adding on top. I assume you want to do the classic *a double break starts a new paragraph* thingy, however this time within parent `<div>` (or certainly other block elements) as well.

I would let do the HTML parser most of the work but I still would work with text search and replace (next to xpath). So what you will see coming is a bit hackish but I think pretty stable:

First of all I would select all text-nodes that are of top-level or child of the said div.

```
(.|./div)/text()
```

This xpath is relative to an *anchor* element which is the `<body>` tag as it represents the root-tag of your HTML fragment when loaded into `DOMDocument`.

If child of a div then I would insert the starting paragraph at the very beginning.

Then in any case I would insert a break-mark (here in form of a comment) at each occurrence of the sequence that starts a new paragraph (that should be `"\n\n"` because of whitespace normalization, I might be wrong and if it doesn't apply, you would need to do the whitespace-normalization upfront to have this working transparently).

```
/* @var $result DOMText[] */
$result = $xp->query('(.|./div)/text()', $anchor);

foreach ($result as $i => $node)
{
    if ($node->parentNode->tagName == 'div')
    {
        $insertBreakMarkBefore($node, true);
    }

    while (FALSE !== $pos = strpos($node->data, $paragraphSequence))
    {
        $node = $node->splitText($pos + $paragraphSequenceLength);
        $insertBreakMarkBefore($node);
    }
}
```

These inserted break-marks are just there to be replaced with a HTML `<p>` tag. A HTML parser will turn those into adequate `<p>...</p>` pairs so I can spare myself writing that algorithm (even though, this might be interesting). This basically work like I once outlined in some other answer but I just don't find the link any longer:

1. After the modification of the DOM tree, get the innter HTML of the `<body>` again.
2. Replace the set marks with `"<p>"` (here I mark the class as well to make this visible)
3. Load the HTML fragment into the parser again to re-create the DOM with the proper `<p>...</p>` pairs.
4. Obtain the HTML again from the `DOMDocument` parser, which now is finally.

These outlined steps in code (skipping some of the function definitions for a moment):

```
$needle  = sprintf('%1$s<!--%2$s-->%1$s', $paragraphSequence, $paragraphComment);
$replace = sprintf("\n<p class=\"%s\">\n", $paragraphComment);
$html    = strtr($innerHTML($anchor), array($needle . $needle => $replace, $needle => $replace));

echo "HTML afterwards:\n", $innerHTML($loadHTMLFragment($html));
```

As this shows, double sequences are replaced with a single one. Probably one at the end need to be deleted as well (if applicale, you could also trim whitespace here).

The final HTML output:

```
<div>
<p class="break">

    This text should be wrapped in a p tag.
</p>
</div>
<p class="break">
This also should be wrapped.
</p>
<p class="break">
<b>And</b> this.</p>
```

Some more post-production for nice output formatting can be useful, too. Actually I think it's worth to do as it will help you tweak the algorithm ([Full Demo](https://eval.in/42588) - just seeing, whitespace normalization probably does not apply there. so use with care).

Comment: Nice explanation, however, your demo doesn't seem to actually achieve this result.

Comment: As written at the very end, this is because of the missing whitespace normalization. Ensure the input uses `\n` as line-separator, the codepad seems to use `\r\n` or something simmilar which is why you see it different. I can re-check that later again, I just noticed when I pasted it there, on my own box the code works. So try for yourself, it might already work on your box.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with pure JavaScript if you wish:

```
var content = document.evaluate(
                                      '//text()', 
                                      document, 
                                      null, 
                                      XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, 
                                      null );

for ( var i=0 ; i < content .snapshotLength; i++ ){
  console.log( content .snapshotItem(i).textContent );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it is not xpath but check this out:

PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

**Features**

A HTML DOM parser written in PHP5+ let you manipulate HTML in a very easy way!

Supports invalid HTML.

Find tags on an HTML page with selectors just like jQuery.

Extract contents from HTML in a single line.

Comment: Please show in your answer how it works with that library, otherwise this is only partly related (and for my personal taste, that library is a bad suggestion, PHP nowadays has everything built-in what that library offers, that *PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser* library was originally written for PHP 4 without the libxml based extensions as they did not exist so far.